# React FIrebase Failed-precondition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im using Firebase to store some data in my React app. Its working fine on my local emulator with the same settings, but when i publish the app, i get this error:
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.12.1): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: {"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"}

Im using the where() clause, and i red i need to add some sort of index in my firebase rules.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (activeList === 'null') {
    } else {
      const userRef = collection(database, activeList.id);
      const sort = query(userRef, where("checked", "==", showDoneTodos), orderBy('title', 'asc'))
      const unsubsctibeAllTodos = onSnapshot(sort, (snapshot) => {
        setAllTodos(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.data().id,
          title: doc.data().title,
          desc: doc.data().desc,
          checked: doc.data().checked
        })
        ))
      })

      return () => {
        unsubsctibeAllTodos()
      }
    }
  }, [activeList, showDoneTodos])
```

Some info:
activeList is an object with and ID. The problem is that this is generated live so i cant preconfigure any collection ID before i publish.

showDoneTodos is a boolean.

Any guidance would be very welcome!

### Thanks!

Comment: The error must must have a link in browser console? Have you tried following it and creating the required index?

Comment: No link in the console. That is the only error showing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Firebase does not provide a link to create the necessary index anymore. They only provide the error code:`{"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"}`

The solution is the same, go to Firebase -> Indexes and add it there...

[image: firebase index rules]

Answer (score 1):

Firebase logs this error when the required index is missing. It only shows this error when you use the onSnapshot method. When you use the getDocs methode it will show the good old link to create the index in the Firebase console. A solution is to create a similar request with the getDoc methode, create the index and switch back to the onSnapshot methode.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled a lot with this. Most of the time is related to missing indexes. However, sometimes you don't get the index build link in the error message.

If you build the index by hand in Firebase, keep in mind that ASCending is the default value. So don't enable DESCending instead of it if you don't use it.